# Use np.einsum to replace for loop

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I want to make the following computation, i use random arrays for demonstration:

```
a = np.random.randint(10, size=(100,3))
b = np.random.randint(10, size=(3,2))

result = np.zeros(100)

for i in range(100):
    result[i] = a[i] @ b @ b.T @ a[i].T
```

To speed up the calculation, i thought about removing the for loop by an einsteins sum.
So I tried the following, with the same vectors:

```
result = np.einsum('ij,jk,jk,ij->i', a, b, b, a)
```

I put the 'i' on the right hand side of the einsum, because the result vector shows a correct size. However, the result is slightly different.

Can my problem be solved with an einsum?

Franz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one `einsum`, it would be -

```
np.einsum('ij,jl,kl,ik->i',a,b,b,a)
```

Bringing in `matrix-multiplication` with `np.dot` -

```
np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->i',a,b.dot(b.T),a)
```

Or with more of it -

```
np.einsum('ij,ij->i',a.dot(b.dot(b.T)),a)
```

With `np.matmul/@-operator in Python 3.x`, it translates to -

```
((a@(b@b.T))[:,None,:] @ a[:,:,None])[:,0,0]
```

Comment: Awesome!
I did some timing tests and came to the following results:
**Method 1**: `665 us    `     
**Method 2**: `59 us      `      
**Method 3**: `19.64 us     `     
**Method 4**: `13.45 us     `     
**Method 5**: `12.11 us     `     
Every solution is a large improvement in comparison to the original for-loop(Method 1). The last one is the fastest, but i think Method 4 is easier to understand.